# Get the data from multiple URL API

Tags: python, api, url

I'm currently new at coding, and I'm trying to get the GDP of Mexico using the API of the government. The problems is that this API only let me select 10 economic indicators at a time. So for the data that I want I need 100 URL APIs :S
Is there a way that I can put all the URL links at python and it'll give me all the information?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide details of the API and the code you're having a problem with

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).